# Como alterar o nome da Rota para minusculo?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, restful, swagger

No swagger aparece a primeira letra de cada palavra em maiusculo WeatherForecast:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Pesquise e não encontrei como faço para exibir tudo em minusculo e preciso que tudo fique em minusculo e acrescentei o atributo `Name = "weatherforecast"` mas vejo que isso não é o suficiente:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]", Name = "weatherforecast")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mudar essa configuração através das configurações de rota do `.net` mesmo.

Inclua a configuração abaixo no registro das dependências da DI.

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
    options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
});
```

Detalhes sobre a documentação [aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routeoptions.lowercaseurls?view=aspnetcore-3.1).